# Finding and removing outliers in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

Suppose I sample a selection of database records that return the following numbers:

```
20.50, 80.30, 70.95, 15.25, 99.97, 85.56, 69.77
```

Is there an algorithm that can be efficiently implemented in PHP to find the outliers (if there are any) from an array of floats based on how far they deviate from the mean?

Comment: Outlier based on what?

Comment: perhaps with math extension: [http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stats.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stats.php)

Comment: @llnk based on the numbers in the given result. From what I understand, the outliers would be based on the inner and outer quartiles...but then again, I readily admit I'm not great at statistical math.

Comment: @EcomEvolution There's many ways of determining outliers - do you mean 'n' standard deviations from the mean?

Comment: @EcomEvolution: "based on the numbers" is pretty generic way to analyize outliers

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse Basically, yes. Trying to figure something out that is adjustable because I have to test how effective it is on a lot of result sets to determine how much data should be kept for analysis. For instance, 15.25 and 20.50 would throw off the results. So I need a way to find such number.

Comment: count() and sort(). Use the count to identify how many elements you want to remove from each end, then array_pop() and array_shift() to remove them; or you could use array_slice() to extract the  ones you want to keep into a new array

Comment: @EcomEvolution The problem is that using such a method requires knowledge of your data - it only applies to normal distributions. Hence (in part) why there are other methods. In addition it's a fairly arbitrary definition.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse What I posted is an actual example of my data. Literally, a series of floats. If any fall too far off center of the mean, I need to be able to identify them. If none are too far off, then there is nothing to remove. Judging by the comments, I get the feeling I may have misphrased my question.

Comment: How should anybody here on site be able (given we don't know you) to answer the question if you're able to implement something or not? Especially as you're already asking it looks like that you're not able to do that.

Comment: @hakre Odd that you'd focus on that part of the question. Regardless, I've changed the wording to help with the confusion based on the comments here. I clearly didn't explain myself very well.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Ok let's assume you have your data points in an array like so:

```
<?php $dataset = array(20.50, 80.30, 70.95, 15.25, 99.97, 85.56, 69.77); ?>
```

Then you can use the following function (see comments for what is happening) to remove all numbers that fall outside of the mean +/- the standard deviation times a magnitude you set (defaults to 1):

```
<?php

function remove_outliers($dataset, $magnitude = 1) {

  $count = count($dataset);
  $mean = array_sum($dataset) / $count; // Calculate the mean
  $deviation = sqrt(array_sum(array_map("sd_square", $dataset, array_fill(0, $count, $mean))) / $count) * $magnitude; // Calculate standard deviation and times by magnitude

  return array_filter($dataset, function($x) use ($mean, $deviation) { return ($x <= $mean + $deviation && $x >= $mean - $deviation); }); // Return filtered array of values that lie within $mean +- $deviation.
}

function sd_square($x, $mean) {
  return pow($x - $mean, 2);
} 

?>
```

For your example this function returns the following with a magnitude of 1:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 80.3
    [2] => 70.95
    [5] => 85.56
    [6] => 69.77
)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works quite well. I'm good with algorithms but strangely terrible at math. Not sure how that happened! :)

Comment: @EcomEvolution NP... the `$filter` part was unnecessary didn't realise I posted it so you can remove it. Also I'm not the best at math so I used wikipedia for this.

Comment: I need a function to remove outliers from an array and I come across your answer. Erm, why not just set `$magnitude = 1` in the argument list instead of setting it to `NULL` first, and then assigning 1 to it afterwards? :)

Comment: @mavili I actually didn't realise PHP allowed default argument values and was using PHP's type hinting (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) to make it an optional parameter. Now I know this has been updated.

Comment: genius. this is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: This is cool and all. For an absolute noob in math, what does the magnitude do, and why default 1? what would 2,3,4 do?

Comment: With a dataset looking like this: $dataset = [0.06789,0.06790,0.067895]; it will return [
  2 => 0.067895
]

To me it should return all 3

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 standard deviation is a measurement of how much the numbers in your data set vary. Magnitude in this function multiplies that, 1 means it removes numbers 1 standard deviation away from the mean, 2 means it removes numbers 2 standard deviations away from the mean... etc.

In your case if you use a magnitude of 2 or 3 you will get all the numbers back.

The magnitude you use is up to you and how much variance you want in the numbers. The best thing to do is test with real data and settle on a magnitude that gives a result you are happy with.

Answer (score 1):

For a normally distributed set of data, removes values more than 3 standard deviations from the mean.

```
<?php
function remove_outliers($array) {
    if(count($array) == 0) {
      return $array;
    }
    $ret = array();
    $mean = array_sum($array)/count($array);
    $stddev = stats_standard_deviation($array);
    $outlier = 3 * $stddev;
    foreach($array as $a) {
        if(!abs($a - $mean) > $outlier) {
            $ret[] = $a;
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: I like this and it works, but the client's I'm developing for don't want to have to install a PECL extension. Unfortunately that meant being unable to use the stats library. Thanks for your input and helping me clarify what I was going for!

Answer (score 0):

Topic: Detecting local, additive outliers in unordered arrays by walking a small window through the array and calculating the standard deviation for a certain range of values.

Good morning folks,

here is my solution much to late, but since I was looking for detecting outliers via PHP and could'nt find anything basic, I decided somehow smoothing a given dataset in a timeline of 24 h by simply moving a range of 5 items in a row through an unordered array and calculate the local standard deviation to detect the additive outliers.

The first function will simply calculate the average and deviation of a given array, where $col means the column with the values (sorry for the freegrades, this means that in an uncomplete dataset of 5 values you only have 4 freegrades - I don't know the exact english word for Freiheitsgrade):

```
function analytics_stat ($arr,$col,$freegrades = 0) {

// calculate average called mu
$mu = 0;
foreach ($arr as $row) {
    $mu += $row[$col];
}
$mu = $mu / count($arr);

// calculate empiric standard deviation called sigma
$sigma = 0;
foreach ($arr as $row) {
    $sigma += pow(($mu - $row[$col]),2);
}
$sigma = sqrt($sigma / (count($arr) - $freegrades));

return [$mu,$sigma];
}
```

Now its time for the core function, which will move through the given array and create a new array with the result. Margin means the factor to multiply the deviation with, since only one Sigma detects to many outliers, whereas more than 1.7 seems to high:

```
function analytics_detect_local_outliers ($arr,$col,$range,$margin = 1.0) {

$count = count($arr);
if ($count < $range) return false;

// the initial state of each value is NOT OUTLIER
$arr_result = [];
for ($i = 0;$i < $count;$i++) {
    $arr_result[$i] = false;
}

$max = $count - $range + 1;
for ($i = 0;$i < $max;$i++) {

    // calculate mu and sigma for current interval
    // remember that 5 values will determine the divisor 4 for sigma
    // since we only look at a part of the hole data set
    $stat = analytics_stat(array_slice($arr,$i,$range),$col,1);

    // a value in this interval counts, if it's found outside our defined sigma interval
    $range_max = $i + $range;
    for ($j = $i;$j < $range_max;$j++) {
        if (abs($arr[$j][$col] - $stat[0]) > $margin * $stat[1]) {
            $arr_result[$j] = true;

            // this would  be the place to add a counter to isolate
            // real outliers from sudden steps in our data set
        }
    }
}

return $arr_result;
}
```

And finally comes the test function with random values in an array with length 24.
As for margin I was curious and choose the Golden Cut PHI = 1.618 ... since I really like this number and some Excel test results have led me to a margin of 1.7, above which outliers very rarelly were detected. The range of 5 is variable, but for me this was enough. So for every 5 values in a row there will be a calculation:

```
function test_outliers () {

// create 2 dimensional data array with items [hour,value]
$arr = [];
for ($i = 0;$i < 24;$i++) {
    $arr[$i] = [$i,rand(0,500)];
}

// set parameter for detection algorithm
$result = [];
$col = 1;
$range = 5;
$margin = 1.618;
$result = analytics_detect_local_outliers ($arr,$col,$range,$margin);

// display results
echo "<p style='font-size:8pt;'>";
for ($i = 0;$i < 24;$i++) {
    if ($result[$i]) echo "&diams;".$arr[$i][1]."&diams; "; else echo $arr[$i][1]." ";
}
echo "</p>";
}
```

After 20 calls of the test function I got these results:

> 417 140 372 131 449 26 192 222 320 349 94 147 201 ♦342♦ 123 16 15
>   ♦490♦ 78 190 ♦434♦ 27 3 276
>
> 379 440 198 135 22 461 208 376 286 ♦73♦ 331 358 341 14 112 190 110 266
>   350 232 265 ♦63♦ 90 94
>
> 228 ♦392♦ 130 134 170 ♦485♦ 17 463 13 326 47 439 430 151 268 172 342
>   445 477 ♦21♦ 421 440 219 95
>
> 88 121 292 255 ♦16♦ 223 244 109 127 231 370 16 93 379 218 87 ♦335♦ 150
>   84 181 25 280 15 406
>
> 85 252 310 122 188 302 ♦13♦ 439 254 414 423 216 456 321 85 61 215 7
>   297 337 204 210 106 149
>
> 345 411 308 360 308 346 ♦451♦ ♦77♦ 16 498 331 160 142 102 ♦496♦ 220
>   107 143 ♦241♦ 113 82 355 114 452
>
> 490 222 412 94 2 ♦480♦ 181 149 41 110 220 ♦477♦ 278 349 73 186 135 181
>   ♦39♦ 136 284 340 165 438
>
> 147 311 246 449 396 328 330 280 453 374 214 289 489 185 445 86 426 246
>   319 ♦30♦ 436 290 384 232
>
> 442 302 ♦436♦ 50 114 15 21 93 ♦376♦ 416 439 ♦222♦ 398 237 234 44 102
>   464 204 421 161 330 396 461
>
> 498 320 105 22 281 168 381 216 435 360 19 ♦402♦ 131 128 66 187 291 459
>   319 433 86 84 325 247
>
> 440 491 381 491 ♦22♦ 412 33 273 256 331 79 452 314 485 66 138 116 356
>   290 190 336 178 298 218
>
> 394 439 387 ♦80♦ 463 369 ♦104♦ 388 465 455 ♦246♦ 499 70 431 360 ♦22♦
>   203 280 241 319 ♦34♦ 238 439 497
>
> 485 289 249 ♦416♦ 228 166 217 186 184 ♦356♦ 142 166 26 91 70 ♦466♦ 177
>   357 298 443 307 387 373 209
>
> 338 166 90 122 442 429 499 293 ♦41♦ 159 395 79 307 91 325 91 162 211
>   85 189 278 251 224 481
>
> 77 196 37 326 230 281 ♦73♦ 334 159 490 127 365 37 57 246 26 285 468
>   228 181 74 ♦455♦ 119 435
>
> 328 3 216 149 217 348 65 433 164 473 465 145 341 112 462 396 168 251
>   351 43 320 123 181 198
>
> 216 213 249 219 ♦29♦ 255 100 216 181 233 33 47 344 383 ♦94♦ 323 440
>   187 79 403 139 382 37 395
>
> 366 450 263 160 290 ♦126♦ 304 307 335 396 458 195 171 493 270 434 222
>   401 38 383 158 355 311 150
>
> 402 339 382 97 125 88 300 332 250 ♦86♦ 362 214 448 67 114 ♦354♦ 140 16
>   ♦354♦ 109 0 168 127 89
>
> 450 5 232 155 159 264 214 ♦416♦ 51 429 372 230 298 232 251 207 ♦322♦
>   160 148 206 293 446 111 338

I hope, this will help anyone in the present or future.
Greetings

P.S. To further improve this algorithm you may add a counter, which makes sure, that a certain value must for instance be found at least 2 times, that means in 2 different intervals or windows, before it is labeled as outlier. So a sudden jump of the following values does not make the first value the villain. Let me give you an example:

In 3,6,5,9,37,40,42,51,98,39,33,45 there is an obvious step from 9 to 37 and an isolated value 98. I would like to detect 98, but not 9 or 37.
The first interval 3,6,5,9,37 would detect 37, the second interval 6,5,9,37,40 not. So we would not detect 37, since there is only one problematic interval or one match. Now it should be clear, that 98 counts in 5 intervals and is therefore an outlier. So lets declare a value an outlier, if it "counts" at least 2 times.
Like so often we have to look closely the borders, since they have only one interval, and make for these values an exception.