# Removing Lower Outliers in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, outliers

I've been using this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15175353/2031148) to remove outliers from a dataset to a magnitude of 1.

This works great for removing large numbers, but it does not remove lower outliers.

From the following dataset for example: `(0, 1, 344, 345, 10000)` it would keep `0, 1` when I'd like them removed.

How can I edit the code from the above linked answer to remove the lower outliers too?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you only have very few numbers and a **very high standard deviation** (mean: 2138, standard deviation: about 4400).

You could adjust the magnitude, but that doesn't seem to be a good solution here. I think it's best to work with the **median** in your case (see here how to implement the function: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/223). Simply put: the median is the value in the middle.

So your function could look like this:

```
function removeOutliers($arr, $alpha = 0.8, $beta = 1.2) {
  $median = array_median($arr);
  // assuming the array is sorted after median calculation
  $bound = $median * $alpha;
  $lower = 0;
  while ($arr[$lower] < $bound)
    $lower++;
  $bound = $median * $beta;
  $upper = count($arr) - 1;
  while ($arr[$upper] > $bound)
    $upper--;
  return array_slice($arr, $lower, $upper - $lower + 1);
}
```